# Typecaste char[] into structure and retrieve the values of the structure.?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  //      std::cout
using namespace std;
struct mystruct
{

        unsigned int a;
        unsigned char b;
        unsigned long long c;
};
 int main ()
{
        unsigned char str[1];
        unsigned int a,b,c;
        str[0]=1;  // str[0]=??????
        mystruct* obj = (mystruct *)(&(str[0]));
        c=obj->c;
        a=(unsigned int)obj->a;
        b=(unsigned int)obj->b;
        cout<<"a="<<a<<"\t b="<<b<<"\t c="<<c<<endl;

}
```

Is it possible do the above thing? If yes, then:
What should I fill in `str[0]` so that I get value of `a=1,b=257,c=1`?

currently I'm getting below output:

```
a=1     b=0     c=8388449
```

Comment: You have some serious undefined behaviour there, and padding issues otherwise.

Comment: `mystruct* obj = (mystruct *)(&(str[0]));` is not valid.

Comment: Not only is the structure `str` not large enough it is not guaranteed to be correctly aligned for any particular type.

Comment: You have an array containing one single byte, and expect to be able to access it like a structure containing at least 16 (including padding) bytes?

Comment: `mystruct` can store 13 bytes of data. On the other hand, `str` is 1 byte long. What are you doing?

Comment: "Is it possible do the above thing?" what "thing" do you mean? please tell us in words what you actually would like to achieve with the shown code.

Comment: Tell us what you're really trying to do (and not how). Looks like you have no idea what you're doing (e.g.: creating an array with *one* element)

Comment: in actual code str[1] is itself a part of another structure. and str[0] is being typecasted into another structre which is same as above structure "mystruct".

Comment: The code is pre written M jus trying to understand it.

Comment: `b` is too small to hold `257`.

Comment: _Is it possible do the above thing?_ it's possible to do many many things which are invalid, wrong, or even painful. You've stumbled upon two, if not all three of those in this question.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are coding for a microcontroller on a compiler with very defined semantics, you shouldn't be doing that. The reason is that the struct could have paddings, the computer could be little or big endian, `sizeof(int)` is not the same on all computers, and `char` is not necessarily 8 bits either.

This is besides the fact that your `str` is too short anyway.

While this is undefined behavior in C, on microcontrollers these things are often well-defined and can be used. One example would be:

```
unsigned char str[sizeof(struct mystruct)];

struct mystruct* obj = (void *)str;
```

To know the conversion between the contents of `str` and `obj`, you would need to exactly know how your compiler pads the struct as well as the sizeof each member and the endian-ness of the computer.

Again, unless in very specific locations, this kind of coding is plain wrong.

Comment: `char` is one byte, always.  By definition.  (Of course, the number of bits in a byte can vary.)